# In shopify is it possible to grab variant metadata on products?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm working on an embedded app extension and need to grab product variant metadata on a specific collections page. Is it possible to grab the metadata the same way you can on a product show page?

For example:

```
const product = {{ product | json }} 
const products = {{ products | json }}
```

This is working for me on the Product show page:

`const variantMetadata = {{ product.variants[0].metafields.custom | json }}`

But if I try and access metadata from **products** on my Test collections page, I get undefined.

`products[0].variants[0].metafields`

They are both referencing the same product with the first variant in the array containing the custom metadata namespace. Does anyone know why I can't access my custom metafields on the collections page?

Comment: use `{{colleciton.products}}` to get the products into a particular collection on collection template in Shopify

Answer (score -1):

You need to be a little more organized, and then you might achieve success. First off, on a collection page you do not have a product. So you need to iterate the collection itself as in:

`{% for product in collection.products %}`

Now that gives you a product if the collection has any we can get the first (and perhaps only variant) as

{% product.variants[0] %} since there is no need to iterate as you hard-coded JSON into that variant's metafield of choice. Getting a specific metafield is now your job and you might as well be precise and use proper nomenclature as in

`{% for mf in variant.metafields %}` to iterate all metafields on the variant and then check for the namespace and key that match to get one, we label *mf*:

`mf.namespace.key` where it matches your needs.

To extract the JSON. Note that you can get JSON without running JSON metafields through a filter. Confusing as heck, but a teeny amount of experimentation reveals it all to you.

By this I mean these options to confuse the neophytes:

`mf.my_custom_name.my_special_key.value`   or
`mf.my_custom_name.my_special_key.value | JSON` or
`mf.my_custom_name.my_special_key | JSON`

That should do you fine.

Comment: Correct, I don't have a **product** on the collections page. I was using this as an example to illustrate the metafield object I'm trying to access. Perhaps I should have left this part out to avoid confusion

To answer your suggestion, if I grab the collection, `const collection = {{ collection | json }}` and log collection.products it returns undefined. The collection var itself is defined, but doesn't contain a **products** key in the object to iterate over.

Comment: That being said, there are products in my collection. On my collection page I have access to `const products = {{ products | json }}` **products** plural, but then I run into my original issue of not being able to access the metafield on a product's variant.

Comment: You're definitely doing something wrong. Collections do indeed have an array of products. Just adding to your burden of things to learn I guess! 

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/collection#collection-products